# How to use interpn?

Tags: scipy, interpolation

I am trying to use interpn (in python using Scipy) to replicate results from Matlab using interp3. However, I am struggling to structure my arguments. I tried the following line:

```
f = interpn(blur_maps, fx, fy, pyr_level)
```

Where blur maps is a `600 x 800 x 7` representing a grayscale image at seven levels of blur,
`fx` and `fy` are indices of the seven maps. Both `fx` and `fy` are 2d arrays. `pyr_level` is a 2d array that contains values from 1 to 7 representing the blur map to be interpolated.

My question is since I incorrectly arranged the arguments, how can I arrange them in a way that works? I tried to look up examples but I didn't see anything similar. Here is an example of the data I am trying to interpolate:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2, math
from scipy.interpolate import interpn

levels = 7

img_path = '/Users/alimahdi/Desktop/i4.jpg'
img = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(img_path), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
row, col = img.shape

x_range = np.arange(0, col)
y_range = np.arange(0, row)
fx, fy = np.meshgrid(x_range, y_range)

e = np.exp(np.sqrt(fx ** 2 + fy ** 2))
pyr_level = 7 * (e - np.min(e)) / (np.max(e) - np.min(e))


blur_maps = np.zeros((row, col, levels))
blur_maps[:, :, 0] = img

for i in range(levels - 1):
    img = cv2.pyrDown(img)
    r, c = img.shape

    tmp = img
    for j in range(int(math.log(row / r, 2))):
        tmp = cv2.pyrUp(tmp)

    blur_maps[:, :, i + 1] = tmp

pixelGrid = [np.arange(x) for x in blur_maps.shape]
interpPoints = np.array([fx.flatten(), fy.flatten(), pyr_level.flatten()])
interpValues = interpn(pixelGrid, blur_maps, interpPoints.T)
finalValues = np.reshape(interpValues, fx.shape)
```

I am now getting the following error: `ValueError: One of the requested xi is out of bounds in dimension 0` I do know that the problem is in `interpPoints` but I am not sure how to fix it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for `scipy.interpolate.interpn` states that the first argument is a grid of the data you are interpolating over (which is just the integers of the pixel numbers), second argument is data (`blur_maps`) and third arguments is the interpolation points in the form `(npoints, ndims)`. So you would have to do something like:

```
import scipy.interpolate

pixelGrid = [np.arange(x) for x in blur_maps.shape] # create grid of pixel numbers as per the docs
interpPoints = np.array([fx.flatten(), fy.flatten(), pyr_level.flatten()]) 

# interpolate
interpValues = scipy.interpolate.interpn(pixelGrid, blur_maps, interpPoints.T)

# now reshape the output array to get in the original format you wanted
finalValues = np.reshape(interpValues, fx.shape)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort. However, the pixelGrid line takes too long to execute. There should be some other war around. Anyways, I added an example code of what I am looking for.

Comment: I'm sorry--I had a type in my original answer. I think the issue with the pixelGrid taking too long should be fixed in the answer now. It was using `blur_maps.size` when it should use `blur_maps.shape`.

Comment: The shape worked like charm, but I still cannot interpolate. Now I am getting the following error:

ValueError: The requested sample points xi have dimension 786432, but this RegularGridInterpolator has dimension 3

Comment: Okay, the issue is that the `interpPoints` had a shape of `(3, npoints)`, where as it needs to have shape `(npoints, 3)`, so you can fix this by transposing `interpPoints`. I have edited the solution to reflect this.

Comment: I have already tried that. I also did apply your updated code and I get the following error: ValueError: One of the requested xi is out of bounds in dimension 0

Comment: @AliMajeedMahdi Could it be that you got the dimension order wrong? `fx` is the column and `fy` the row, so it should be `interpPoints = np.array([fy.flatten(), fx.flatten(), pyr_level.flatten()])` ?

Comment: @Jason I already tried that. Still does not solve the problem.

Comment: try linespace instead of nrange. I know it sounds crazy, but it works. I had exactly the same problem, and I still don't know why but it works.